# c++ program doesn't execute with `#include<cmath>`

Tags: c++, cmath

I'm writing a program for my class that solves a few problems one after another. This part:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    ifstream data;
    data.open("data.txt");

    //LOAD VALUES
    int d[200][320];

    for(int i=0;i<200;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<320;j++){
            data>>d[i][j];
        }
    }

int m=1,c=0;//max length, current length

    for(int i=0;i<320;i++){//columns
        for(int j=1;j<200;j++){//rows

            if(d[i][j]==d[i][j-1])c+=1;
            else if(c>m){
                m=c;    
                c=0;
            }
            else c=0;

        }
    }

    cout<<"max length: "<<m<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

searches for the longest vertical line of identical values in an array. I commented other parts of the program, one of which requires the `cmath`library. 
When I compile the above part with`#include<cmath>` the execution lasts unreasonably long and gives no output on `cout`, just a blank line. It works properly when I don't include `cmath`. Any idea why this is so and how to fix it? 
Here's the link to ["data.txt"](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Jq4Zf48NXsOPIVqgbEIVeLvxOQv79XyK6EGBLULiicM)

Edit: It stopped working even after deleting `#inclde<cmath>`. Whether the program executes correctly seems to be completely random.

Comment: Can you show the entire program including how `d` is declared and the include of `<cmath.h>` ?

Comment: What is the function that contains this lines?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a [mcve]. Also please try to use a debugger to step through your code statement by statement to make sure it does what it's supposed to do.

Comment: When you perform the comparison, there is a confusion between rows and columns

Comment: Did a previous broken version define and call any other functions in addition to `main`?

Comment: Don't use magic numbers. Those `200`s and `320`s don't belong there. Start with `const int columns = 320; const int rows = 200;` and use those names instead of the values. And, related, instead of `i` and `j`, use meaningful names. I'd probably use `column` and `row`. Once you do that, the problem should jump out at you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including `cmath` has nothing to do with your issue.

You have undefined behavior called buffer overflow when analyzing data.
Here is [live demo with index checking](https://wandbox.org/permlink/4YiOIicQ1v4ySBoA) (exception is thrown).
Basically you have messed up order of indexes.

Here is [fixed version of your code](https://wandbox.org/permlink/uQpfGM0OUwSDByrY) (with index checking).

BTW your code is very messy, learn to split code into smaller functions. [Primitive demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/6dNXoJ3ubJ8W23e0) (can be done better, but for beginner should be fine).